# Transaction handling in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

First of all, I do know that Entity Framework has some default transaction handling.

I am currently working on a scheduling tool. Now my question: how can I ensure when two users try to book the same appointment at the same time that only one of them occurs in the database?

This is my code without checking anything.

```
    public async Task<Appointment> CreateAppointmentAsync(Appointment appointment)
    {
        var entityEntry = _context.Appointments.Add(appointment);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return entityEntry.Entity;
    }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Create a unique key on appointment slot in your database. It's not that easy to enforce arbitrary constraints direct from EF, even with a transaction

Comment: What you ask has little to do with transaction handling. If you use SQL you can solve this easily with an `UPDATE Transactions SET field1=abc,Free=1 ...WHERE slot=@lot and free=0`. This ensures that only a single `UPDATE` would actually update the row. No extra transactions are necessary. It's harder to do with ORMs because you can't update without first reading. The easiest solution here is to use SQL directly

Answer (score 0):

> how can I ensure when two users try to book the same appointment at the same time that only one of them occurs in the database?

The database schema should prevent this from happing.  Typically you simply need a [unique index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes?tabs=data-annotations) that prevents double-booking.

Comment: Though that won't help you with overlapping start / end times.

Comment: True, but even in that case I would prefer to see the database enforce the rule, even if you have to use a trigger, an indexed view, or create appointments through a stored procedure.